# Receive data via Arduino Mega R32060 from MAX485 or USB TTL convertor

Tags: arduino

I am trying to receive something MAX485 or USB TTL convertor with this code for Arduino Mega R32060.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SSerialRX        15
#define SSerialTX        14 
#define SSerialTxControl 3  

#define RS485Transmit    HIGH
#define RS485Receive     LOW

#define Pin13LED         13

SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(SSerialRX, SSerialTX);

int byteReceived;
int byteSend;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Pin13LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SSerialTxControl, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive); 

  RS485Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{  
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, HIGH);
    byteReceived = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(byteReceived);

    digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit);  
    RS485Serial.write(byteReceived);

    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive); 
  }

  if (RS485Serial.available())  //Look for data from other Arduino
  {
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, HIGH);  // Show activity
    byteReceived = RS485Serial.read();    // Read received byte
    Serial.write(byteReceived);        // Show on Serial Monitor
    
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, LOW);  // Show activity 
    Serial.println(byteReceived);
  }
}
```

Pin 3 here is a switch for transmission and reseption modes for MAX485.

I can send data **from** arduino perfectely however.

But condition `RS485Serial.available()` never becomes true. What can be a reason for that?

Comment: it is Mega 2560. it has 4 Serial interfaces so don't use SoftwareSerial on Mega. (and not all pins of Mega support SoftwareSerial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Serial` to read your data. RX 15 and TX 14 is a third serial on Arduino Mega.

Here is MWE for data reading from `Serial3`.

```
int val = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial3.avaliable() > 0) {
    val = Serial3.read();
    Serial.write(val);
  }
}
```